# ListView item not found

Tags: android, android-listview

My app is using landscape full screen mode and the navigation drawer. I am using `listView` in my app along with an `edittext`. The `edittext` is the search bar that will search the `listview`. Both the `listview` and the `edittext` are in the navigation drawer. But, when there is no list item that matches the searched word, the `listview` gets empty.

**So how can I add a "Item not found" message instead of the blank `listview`?**

I searched a lot on the internet and found a method `setEmptyView();` but I couldn't understand it and hence it is not working. Please help me! Maybe this question is already asked here but please give me an easy explanation.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
final String[] data = {"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Flourine","Noen","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    final EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });

    //the code below will automatically close the keyboard when the user will touch the listview

    navList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(navList.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });


  }

}
```

mainactivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Swipe from the left to open the drawer"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:background="#111"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#bfc2d1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint=" search" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notfound"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thought you are new to this site and though you are 14, you have posted a detailed question. Great! BTW, You just missed posting layout code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. should i post the Xml file?

Comment: Yes post it so can better suggest!

Comment: I have posted the xml. Please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have mentioned about setEmptyView() correctly, you should use it if you would want to show empty message whenever ListView gets empty.

Now here is a xml layout and code depicts how to use setEmptyView exactly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTitlebar" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/friendBGColor"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/strNoRecordsFound" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you have to set this empty view (i.e. TextView) to ListView by using:

```
ListView listViewFriends = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFriends);
// set your adapter here
// set your click listener here
// or whatever else
listViewFriends.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

Comment: @user3227476 you haven't taken Empty view and haven't set it to the ListView yet.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke so I got you too exactly, you made me fool by writing that you are new to this site and 14 years old developer. Thanks for that. Accept answer now!

Comment: So you are both are 14....Great! Read your comment again, you have again made a mistake for making someone fool!

Comment: great solution sir but i don't know how to set in TextWatcher please help me

Answer (score 1):

This method is all that you need

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)

Have in mind it accepts a view, so you have to inflate the layout and fill out any/all text you may have there by yourself.

EDIT:

Let's assume you have a layout named "empty_text" like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="There are no entries in this list"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hint: I burned in the string for example purposes, heed the IDE warning and use a string identifier for I18n's sake

Now you would use this code to make it all work with the ListView:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View emptyTextView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_text, null, false);
listView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
```

This code assumes you are executing inside an Activity, but just in case you don't plan on pasting it on an Activity, any [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) instance will work.

That should be it.

Comment: Actually I read the docs but it is so complicated. Can you please help me out with the code?

Comment: Have you read question fully? I doubt it because he has already mentioned something regarding `setEmptyView()`

Comment: Actually i am using a navigation drawer. On the top I have the editext and then the listview. What should i do now?

Comment: The navigation drawer is still inside an Activity, as i said before: any context instance you can get is valid for getting a LayoutInflater

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
lv.setEmptyView(emptyText);
```

Then your listview will automatically use this view when its adapter is empty.

**Detailed Solution:**

Layout:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listViewFriends"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/friendBGColor"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/empty"
android:text="@string/strNoRecordsFound"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Class File:

```
ListView listViewFriends = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFriends);
listViewFriends.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

[Source](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-setemptyview/)